# Trying to install JGit to install EGit and getting error requires package org.kohsuke.args4

Tags: egit, jgit

Trying to install JGit to install EGit and getting error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse JGit Command Line Interface 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
  Missing requirement: JGit Command Line Interface 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.jgit.pgm 2.1.0.201209190230-r) requires 'package org.kohsuke.args4j [2.0.12,2.1.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse JGit Command Line Interface 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r)
    To: org.eclipse.jgit.pgm [2.1.0.201209190230-r]
```

~~~~ **Update** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I gave it the new update site and it said EGit was already installed

So then I went to uninstall it and only one of ~6 Egit entries had the Uninstall button enabled when selected. *(Why won't it let me uninstall them? - ed)* I uninstalled that one hoping maybe it would manage uninstalling all of the entries. *(Why isn't the Uninstall Software option next to the Install new Software option? -ed)*

I then tried to install EGit again and said some plugs were not necessary to be installed because they were already installed *(Why won't it let me over write it? -ed)*. So it let me continue based on the other plugins already being installed.

I restarted as recommended.

I now get this alert and can't open up Flash Builder (Eclipse).

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Eclipse EGit" will be ignored because it is already installed.
```

The log contains this information:

```
!SESSION 2012-10-17 16:38:16.346 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.6.0_35
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/me/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/me/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-17 16:38:16.892
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

*Another developer I know said he tried for a few days to get EGit installed and couldn't. Is this normal? *

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the h t t p://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates repository? This seems to be incomplete, see this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392087.

If you want to install EGit, just use this repository: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/
It contains the latest version of EGit (2.1) plus all necessary dependencies (including JGit).